# Truly Tail-Recursive modInverse() in Prolog

Tags: prolog, numbers

[Rosetta](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_inverse#Prolog) code delivers me the following code snippet
for modinv/3. It does calculate extended GCD via egcd/4 and then
derives from it modinv/3:

```
egcd(_, 0, 1, 0) :- !.
egcd(A, B, X, Y) :-
    divmod(A, B, Q, R),
    egcd(B, R, S, X),
    Y is S - Q*X.
 
modinv(A, B, N) :-
    egcd(A, B, X, Y),
    A*X + B*Y =:= 1,
    N is X mod B.
```

Example queries:

```
?- modinv(42, 2017, N).
N = 1969.

?- modinv(42, 64, X).
false.
```

There is a slight problem with the solution. It is not
tail recursive. Namely the (is)/2 is the last call of
egcd/4 and not egcd/4 itself.

So the predicate might build-up a stack, a stack that
might contain large big numbers. How would one go about
and realize a more tail recursive solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same site you mention has other algorithms amenable for a tail recursive solution.

Here I translated one from the C++ section (note there is a constraint missing in the original C++ code, it is not checking the last value of A):

```
modinv(A, B, N):-
  modinv(A, B, 1, 0, N1),
  (N1 < 0 -> N is N1 + B ; N1 = N).

modinv(A, B, X, Y, N):-
  (B=0 -> (A=1, N=X) ;
   (
     divmod(A, B, Q, R),
     Exp is X - Y * Q,
     modinv(B, R, Y, Exp, N)
   )
  ).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- modinv(42, 2017, N).
N = 1969.

?- modinv(42, 64, X).
false.
```

Comment: With your code modinv(42,64,X) doesn't fail. But it should fail since gcd(42,64)=\=1.

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse: thats a bug in the original C++ code from Rosetta. It was not checking the last value of A being 1. Fixed now

Comment: Cool! Thank you.